# How to recover Spark Master in case of machine failure, where Spark Master was running

Tags: mapreduce, cluster-computing, apache-spark

I have one Spark master on machine A and two Spark workers on another machines B and C. 
If machine A is failed for any reason, Spark master would die in this case.

Is there any way to recover Spark Master or to create a new Spark Master on another machine automatically?

Can anyone help me to resolve this?

Thanks in advance.

Regards, 
Ayush

Answer (score 1):

A [recent pull request](https://github.com/apache/incubator-spark/pull/19) added support for standalone Master fault tolerance using ZooKeeper.  That pull request was just merged into the master branch, so this feature should be incorporated in the 0.9.0 release.  In the meantime, you can try it out by building a development version of Spark.